Reading Data from Databricks Sqlware house using a Databricks Spark cluster
What is the preferred way of accessing a UC enabled SqlWarehouse table from Databricks Spark Cluster .
My requirement is to fetch the data from a sqlwarehouse table(which is present in a different Databricks instance and in a different region) using complex queries, transform it using Pyspark notebook and save the results.
But to fetch data from UC Enabled Sql warehouse, we can use jdbc connection or we can directly access it using spark.sql().
Which one is suggested in this scenario? Also, note that  I need to schedule this notebook for every 30 mins.
Note : Both the Spark cluster and Sql ware house are UC enabled
I tried accessing both the JDBC, Spark.sql but noticed JDBC is equally faster.

Well it depends,

If you have a serverless sql warehouse available, go for JDBC connect, it is most recommended as you don't have to wait for cluster startup and all, and also you will only be paying for what you use. So, it is also a cost effective way.
If you have a all purpose compute which is always running then you can go for spark.sql but it will cost a lot. And if you start the job cluster for each run you have to wait for the cluster startup time.


In Databricks, Tables are not tied to Cluster or SQL Warehouse.
Delta Sharing works best to access a Table from different MetaStore (different Databricks Region).
Delta Sharing Protocol will be faster compared to JDBC.
